# zip: Argument list too long how to make a zip without subfolder?

Tags: command-line, zip

I can't find a way to zip all file inside a folder without the folder itself

```
-tempfolder
--images
---1.jpg
---2.jpg
---3.jpg
```

I need to zip all files inside images folder without creating the folder once I extract them
following this answer ( and others ) I did try this way but without success 
[zip: Argument list too long (80.000 files in overall)](https://superuser.com/questions/272696/zip-argument-list-too-long-80-000-files-in-overall)

```
find images/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | zip images/images.zip -@
```

when I extract files from zip it generate the images folders with all the files inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
find images/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | xargs -l 1000 zip images/images.zip
```

The xargs program will take the stdout from the "|" pipe and add them as
command line arguments.
The `-l` option limits the number of files expanded at a time to 1000.

EDIT

It seems that for the poster the argument list was too long because the
folder path was appended to each of the files, so inflating the list
size by a large factor.

In his case the solution was to add the argument of `-j` or
`--junk-paths`, to store just the name of the file (junk the path),
to not add directory names. So the following was enough:

```
find images/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | zip images/images.zip -@ -j
```

Comment: command line in my question already bypass issue generated if I cd /images/ and then zip -r images.zip * the issue is that when I extract the file it creates an image folder containing all my images file, instead I need to creat a zip that directly extracts alla my images without placing inside a folder

Comment: Do you refer to the argument of `-j` / `--junk-paths`, to store just the name of the file (junk the path), and not to store directory names?

Comment: thanks -j did solve the problem "find images/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | zip images/images.zip -@ -j" work ok if you want update your answer